# Visual Studio SVN integration

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, version-control

Is there any way to properly integrate Subversion control into VS2008? I'm currently using the TortoiseSVN shell extensions, but I keep forgetting to check in new files and it's easy to get in a confused mess.

On another project I use VS2008 with SourceSafe, and it's really nice having most things automated or controlled simply by using VS in its normal way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any free svn for visual studio plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929115/is-there-any-free-svn-for-visual-studio-plugin)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use AnkhSVN myself and so far it has been great, it is free and you can download it here: http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

Answer (score 4):

The [Agent SVN](http://zeusedit.com/agent/) is MS-SCCI plug-in that works with *Visual Studio* and because it is MS-SCCI (as is SourceSafe) it integrates directly with the source control menus found in *Visual Studio*.

> On another project I use VS2008 with SourceSafe, and it's really nice having most things automated or controlled simply by using VS in its normal way.

From inside the VS2008 Agent SVN will feel a lot like SourceSafe.

Answer (score 3):

If you're already using TortoiseSVN, I'd recommend [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/).

It's not free as AnkhSVN, but in my opinion, it's better integrated with VS, works better and more intuitively, and is well worth its registration price.

Comment: +1 I've used VisualSVN as well and it works great. Price I guess would be the deciding factor.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)